# .sh command not working in a desktop launcher

Tags: unity, command-line, bash, launcher, scripts

I'm using a desktop launcher to run `a.sh` script. In `a.sh` I'm calling another script `b.sh` using another user using this command `sudo -u userB /home/userA/Documents/b.sh`. But for some reason it's telling me `sudo: /home/userA/Documents/b.sh: command not found` although `b.sh`is found on this location. If anyone could please advise.

When I run this command:

```
$ namei -m /home/userA/Documents/b.sh
f: /home/userA/Documents/b.sh
 drwxr-xr-x /
 drwxr-xr-x home
 drwxr-xr-x userA
 drwxr-xr-x Documents
 -rw------- b.sh
```

Comment: Does `b.sh` has execute permission for 'userB'?

Comment: Add the output of `namei -m /home/userA/Documents/b.sh`.

Comment: @heemayl I don't know, how to know this?

Comment: @shepherd: Do what muru said, that will do.

Comment: @muru done and edited the question with the result

Comment: @muru any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script lacks read and execute permissions for user B. Do:

```
 chmod og+rx b.sh
```

Comment: so how to permanently give this user the permission?

Comment: instead of writing it in the script

Comment: @shepherd that command is to be run in a terminal. One run, the user permanently has permission, unless you use the chmod command to undo it.

Answer (score 2):

As the permission of the file is `b.sh` is `-rw------- b.sh`, there is no execute bit set for user, group or others. If you want to execute the file as 'userB' then running the following will do:

```
sudo chmod 605 /home/userA/Documents/b.sh
```